# Adding Digital Signature to a word document using Open XML Format in C#

Tags: c#, openxml, digital-signature, cpu-word, .doc

I've created a test word document using openxml. My next step is to add a digital signature at the end of the word document after a button click. Could someone if possible share a code for creating and adding a digital signature to a word file or could just refer to articles that could help me with the same. I've read questions on stackoverflow and read a few articles too but they use Microsoft.interop.office which doesn't work with my word document created by openxml. Please help if possible.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my searches I keep landing on your question, which suggests some awesome SEO.

Anyway, you have probably already arrived at your answer, but I have stumbled across this promising sample:

https://github.com/coatsy/SignWordDoc/blob/master/SignWordDoc/SignWordDoc/Program.cs

I'd say good job coatsy, although I've yet to try it  :D  Hopefully I remember to let you know how it works out.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31460213)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-sign-xml-documents-with-digital-signatures

Comment: Probably mate, but it is better than nothing.  The answer isn't entirely straight forward.  As I said I haven't tried it out so I haven't had the opportunity to do this for myself let alone anyone else.